# What python library should I use for MS Active Directory change notification

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I know there is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python3-ldap lib to work with LDAP. But I dont see that it supports registering for change notifications from Microsoft Active Directory. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: I don't know about MS Active Directory, but you can use the pywin32 win32file module to access the MS [FindFirstChangeNotification API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to [watch a directory for changes](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html#use_findfirstchange).

Comment: Thank you, @martineau. Those links are about file system directory (folder) monitoring and not LDAP (Active directory) monitoring.